# How do you add AWS ASP.NET Core Logging to an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages app?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am looking to use the nuget package [AWS.Logger.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWS.Logger.AspNetCore/) to implement [ASP.NET Core Logging](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aspnet-core-logging) in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages application.

The examples on the project site are based upon ASP.NET Core 1.0.

So the examples show:

In the appsettings.json file:

```
"AWS.Logging": {
  "Region": "us-east-1",
  "LogGroup": "AspNetCore.WebSample",
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

and in Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Read the appsetting.json file for the configuration details
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Create a logging provider based on the configuration information passed through the appsettings.json
    loggerFactory.AddAWSProvider(this.Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());

    ...
```

Can someone please show the equivalent of this in ASP.NET Core 2.0?
And how to then inject the logger into a Razor code behind (.cshtml.cs) page? (I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, not MVC)

I've looked at Microsoft's [page on Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#how-to-add-providers) that shows how to add providers, but I can't figure out how to relate this to adding the AWS Logger within Startup.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is more or less the same for razor

```
public class PersonModel : PageModel {
   ILogger<PersonModel> Logger { get; set; }

    public PersonModel(ILogger<PersonModel> logger)
    {
        this.Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

No matter what,  its as simple as making sure you declare a private type
and then inject within the constructor.    The startup, LoggerFactory is injecting AWS into the logger for you.   You then use logger as Normal.

```
// code to log out to AWS and load the Person.cshtml page
public void GetAsync(){
  Logger.LogInformation("Welcome to the AWS Logger. You are viewing the home page");
}
```